# openglES - give a curved effect to a wall of pictures

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I am starting with openglES (on android).

I have in my app a wall of pictures. I have already made a simple tiled wall where I can browse with translations and zooms, and implemented a simple picking system.

Now I would like to give this wall a curved effect like we can see often (like in safari, see my images)

Do you think i can do it by applying simples (naive..) Y-rotations and Z-translations on each tile?

My first exemple seems to do that wheras my second looks more complicated.

Can you give me some ideas or a solution if you already did it for one of your project??

Exemple 1 : motorola xoom
[image: youtube app xoom]

Exemple 2 : safari top sites
[image: Safari top sites exemple]

Answer (score 0):

Just write it out on paper. Start with a circle of whatever radius you want your pictures laid out in, then figure out the math to calculate a position along that circle for each object and translate/rotate each image/polygon to it's correct location. Then you could do the rest in one of two ways, you could have a rotation variable that rotates all your images around the vertical axis, or you could rotate your camera to look at a different spot on your picture wall. If you wanted to get really fancy, you could apply your images to curved surfaces so that rather than being a bunch of flat polygons, you could actually be looking at the curved images.